# Remap Fn-Key or Win-L-Key on Kubuntu

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, keyboard-layout

My Keyboard has no Key for <, > and |. On Windows i installed a little Tool to map this Symbols to the Win-L-Key. On Linux this doesn't work. I've tried Xmodmap to map <, > and | to the Win-L-Key, but only < and > works. This is the Xmodmap config file

```
keycode 133 = less greater bar
```

also mapping any other symbol at the third position doesn't work. In Firefox nothing works (<, > and | aren't working).

I couldn't map the Fn-Key with Xmodmap, because there is no reaction when i start xev and press the Fn-Key.

After that i tried the KDE Shortcuts, but i can't map anything to the fn-key or the Win-L-Key. KDE shows nothing when i press one of the both keys (others keys are working here).

so whats wrong with Keyboard? Or is this a ubuntu problem?

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using? Please add a screenshot of your keyboard layout handler in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`keycode 133 = less greater bar`

those 3 keysym means: press the key; press with shift; press with **Mode_switch**.

so you need setup Mode_switch key, normally it is null.

eg: use Shift_R (0x3e) as Mode_switch

`keycode 0x3e = Mode_switch Mode_switch`

Fn-key can not be seen by xev or xmodmap.